# Error when joining multiple table

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    refnum as pornum,  tmp_Extract.matnum, matm.matmdescription,
    matm.extradescription, 
    SUM(sqty) AS porqty, CAST(SUM(dqty) AS numeric(16,4)) AS grnqty,   
    (sum(sqty) - sum(dqty)) AS balqty,
    (sum(sorqty) - sum(dorqty)) as balbaseqty,
    puom, pcfactor, apnum   
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         matnum, matmdescription1, isnull(pqty,0) AS sqty, 0 AS dqty,   
         refnum, isnull(qty, 0) as sorqty, 0 as dorqty, 
         puom, pcfactor, apnum, porextractmark 
     FROM 
         por1  
     WHERE
         ((por1.clearflag IS NULL OR por1.clearflag = 0) 
         AND (por1.status <> 'V'))
```

UNION ALL
              SELECT deliverydate FROM porh
              where ((porh.flag ='POR')) and ((porh.status='P'))

UNION ALL

```
     SELECT  
         matnum, matmdescription1, 0 AS sqty, isnull(pqty / porpcfactor, 0) AS dqty, 
         pornum AS refnum, 0 as sorqty, isnull(qty,0) as dorqty,    
         puom, porpcfactor as pcfactor, apnum, porextractmark   
     FROM 
         dbo.grn1       
     WHERE
         grn1.refnum NOT IN (SELECT refnum 
                             FROM grnh 
                             WHERE grnh.status = 'v')) AS tmp_Extract  
LEFT JOIN (
(SELECT matnum, MAX(deliverydate) as deliverydate FROM porh GROUP BY matnum) 
AS tmp_Extract

LEFT JOIN matm on matm.matnum = tmp_Extract.matnum 
where refnum like '%POR%'
GROUP BY refnum, tmp_Extract.matnum,tmp_Extract.puom,tmp_Extract.pcfactor,
apnum,matm.matmdescription,matm.extradescription,
tmp_Extract.deliverydate
having sum(sqty)>sum(dqty)
```

I want to join deliverydate from table `porh` but cannot..anyone can help?

Comment: Welcome to SO; to help the community give a meaningful answer **both** to you and the community please share the table schema **in `create table`** format (no pictures please!) and some sample data (**in `insert into`** format) along with the desired output of your query for the sample data you posted.

Comment: `I want to join deliverydate from table porh but cannot` what do you mean by `cannot` ?

Comment: i have join few table there,which is grn1,por1 and grnh.now i try to join deliverydate column from another table which is called porh ..i try in few way already but cannot. do you have any idea?

Comment: here is full query i try to write

Comment: What is the reason you cannot? beacause you get an error, because you get incorrect results, or because you don't know how to? There's no clue about `porh` anywhere here

Comment: because i dont know to

Comment: is it correct two left join i do right there?

Comment: For starters you should change `AS tmp_Extract.deliverydate ` to `AS tmp_Extract `. I don't know what you're trying to achieve but you probably want to replace `(SELECT DISTINCT  deliverydate FROM porh)` with something like `(SELECT  matnum, MAX(deliverydate) as deliverydate FROM porh GROUP BY matnum)`

Comment: i try to modified this


LEFT JOIN (
(SELECT matnum, MAX(deliverydate) as deliverydate FROM porh GROUP BY matnum) AS tmp_Extract 

LEFT JOIN matm on matm.matnum = tmp_Extract.matnum 
where refnum like '%POR%'
GROUP BY refnum, tmp_Extract.matnum,tmp_Extract.puom,tmp_Extract.pcfactor,
apnum,matm.matmdescription,matm.extradescription,
tmp_Extract.deliverydate
having sum(sqty)>sum(dqty)



then this error come up :
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.


i dont know what is incorrect

Comment: i just want to link deliverydate column from porh table to all of this